# Multiple Where clause in Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to write `MySql` query in Laravel query builder but it returns all data from the table. Most probably the `where` clause not working properly. Also when I put this line `->orWhereNull([$request->name])` then its showing error. As I'm new in Laravel query builder please help me to get out of here.

MySql Query:

```
SELECT t.trans_date, c.cust_id, c.first_name, c.name_name, t.notes_by, t.behavioural_notes
FROM time_trans t
JOIN customers c ON t.cust_id=c.cust_id
WHERE (t.trans_date BETWEEN 'param_date' AND 'param_date')AND (c.cust_id = '10034' OR param = NULL) AND t.behavioural_notes IS NOT NULL
```

Query builder:

```
$data=DB::table('time_trans as t')
            ->join('customers as c','c.cust_id','=','t.cust_id')
            ->select('t.trans_date', 'c.cust_id', 'c.first_name', 'c.name_name', 't.notes_by', 't.behavioural_notes')
            ->WhereBetween('t.trans_date', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date])
            ->WhereNotNull('t.behavioural_notes')
            ->Where('c.cust_id','=',[$request->name])
            ->orWhereNull([$request->name])
            ->get();
```

Comment: `orWhereNull` needs to be the column name, not the value name. If you're going to check for null values on `$request->name`, add that where clause conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this.

```
$data=DB::table('time_trans as t')
         ->join('customers as c','c.cust_id','=','t.cust_id')
        ->select('t.trans_date', 'c.cust_id', 'c.first_name', 'c.name_name', 't.notes_by', 't.behavioural_notes')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->WhereBetween('t.trans_date', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date])
                        ->WhereNotNull('t.behavioural_notes')
                         ->Where('c.cust_id','=',[$request->name]);
            })
        ->orWhereNull([$request->name])
        ->get();
```

Also You need not pass array in orWhereNull([$request->name]). It accepts the single string column name.

**Edited:-**
Looking at Mysql query reformed this

```
$data=DB::table('time_trans as t')
                        ->join('customers as c','c.cust_id','=','t.cust_id')
                        ->select('t.trans_date', 'c.cust_id', 'c.first_name', 'c.name_name', 't.notes_by', 't.behavioural_notes')
                        ->WhereBetween('t.trans_date', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date])
                        ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                            $query->Where('c.cust_id','=',[$request->name])
                                ->orWhereNull(c.cust_id)
                        })
                        ->WhereNotNull('t.behavioural_notes')
                        ->get();
```

Why are you passing $request->param to orWhereNull, it should be the col name. May be the edited Querybuilder can help you. You can update the column name in orWhereNull as per your need.

Comment: Return this`Collection {#293 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: MySql query you have share above returns all records?

Comment: MySql query returns exact record.

Comment: if `$request->param` is null then `orWhereNull` not applicable, that's why I'm trying like this.

Comment: still no results